# Vue composition api not working, data not set with the extracted data from the dabase

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

Trying out the Vue 3 composition API to write some better code but I cant get it to work as I wanted to work. I cant get the values to update with the values from the DB.

```
// component part
<template>
    <SomeChildComponent :value="settings"/>
</template>

// script part
<script>
import { ref, onMounted} from 'vue'
export default {
setup() {

    let settings = ref({
      active : 1,
      update : 0,
      ...
    })

    // this wont change the values
    const getSettingsValues = async () => {  
          const response = await axios.get('/api/settings')// works

          settings.active.value = response.data.active;//undefined
          settings.update.value = 1;//undefined (even with hardcoded value)
          [and more]

     }
     getSettingsValues()

     return { settings };
}
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're misplacing the field `value` when you use the `ref` property, it should be :

```
settings.value.active= response.data.active;
settings.value.update= 1
```